# .xinitrc not sourced in 13.10

Tags: gnome, 13.10, lightdm, xinit

I am using gnome / lightdm / ubuntu 13.10.

I have some customisations I want to do in `~/.xinitrc`, but it seems this file is not being sourced at startup.  I've tried also with `.xsessionrc` and `.xprofile` with no luck.  And reading `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` didn't have any hints for me unfortunately.

My current workaround is just to run a custom shell script after login, but it doesn't seem correct.